# tinyalsa pcm capture using mmap, getting overrun error in pcm_wait()

Tags: c, linux, alsa, tinyalsa

I am using the tinyalsa library to implement audio capturing using mmap. But at the beginning of the program itself I am getting Xrun error ,i.e. overrun in pcm_wait(). I tried varying the buffer size and period, but i think its not able to read from the sound card buffer.

Is there any tutorial on how to use tinyalsa's mmap functions properly. Or even Alsa pcm mmap tutorial?

Comment: Why do you think you need to use mmap?

Comment: @CL I need to access the same sound card twice in a program to capture certain audio. So basically i need to use the captured samples from the sound card buffer and pass it into two threads performing some computation. The pcm_read and pcm_write uses the ioctl() to read and write from the sound card, but i need the memory instead.

Comment: Nothing what you said implies that you need to use mmap.

Comment: @CL then what should be used?

Comment: Plain `snd_pcm_writei()`.

Comment: @anyways irrespective of my requirements, can you help me with pcm_mmap ?

Comment: I won't help you to do something that I know is wrong. Anyway, mmap, when used correctly, has the same timing as `snd_pcm_readi()`, so this would not fix your overrun problem. The error is in your code or in the driver, both of which you have kept secret.